# How do I create a link that points users to the edit profile page?

Tags: navigation

I would like to create a link that leads each user to their edit profile page.

What should I use as URL? I get access denied on the paths I tried, including http://example.com/user/[uid]/edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try using the [Menu Token](https://drupal.org/project/menu_token) module, so you could add a user id token in the path.

Otherwise you'd need to create a page callback in a custom module using hook_menu(), say to 'user/edit', and in that callback, redirect the user to 'user/[uid]/edit'. That way you could add a menu link to 'user/edit' and it would work. See [this comment](https://drupal.org/node/102162#comment-4270396) for an example.

Comment: I created a page callback based on the example and i still get "access denied message". Please what could be wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Do the users have permission to view / edit their own profiles on the permissions page?

Comment: Yes they do. I have also given the required permissions for profile 2. Does it matter that i have field permissions installed?